# Find the good regex in eclipse

Tags: eclipse

I would like to know if it's possible to filter code line from a search with eclipse.

Example: I have to extract all part of code between `""` excluding all line starting with 'logger' and also all comment starting with `//`. I didn't find the exact RegEx to do that...

Can you help me please? Thanks in advance. Best regards.

Comment: `^((?:[^\r\n"](?!logger)(?!//))++)("[^"]*+")`: first group (`\1`) contains characters before first `"..."`, second group (`\2`) matches `"..."`.

Comment: This is awesome. You made my day. I thank you a lot for this regex. And i want to apologize for my vocabulary. I'm french, that's the reason why. Thanks again . Have a good day. Cordially

Comment: You are welcome. I like to use [DeepL](https://www.deepl.com/translator) to translate which also supports French to English.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **`^((?:[^\r\n"](?!logger)(?!//))++)("[^"]*+")`** for that:

- the first group (`\1`) will contain the characters before the first `"..."` in a line,
- the second group (`\2`) matches `"..."`.

The restriction of this regular expression is that only the first `"..."` in a line will be matched.